# Quickly assigning an id to a given combination of bits

Tags: python, optimization, binary

the context behind my issue is not important, as my question itself is fairly self-contained.

Im currently trying to assign numbers to sequences of bits. Such that, if i ask `functionA` for bit sequence 42, it would return the corresponding bits, say "0110101011..." (not correct, just an example), and if i gave `functionB` the sequence "0110101011...", it could give me the number 42.

Currently, the way im assigning each sequence's number is through the pattern

```
  bits   val  
| 0    | 0    |
| 1    | 1    |
| 00   | 2    |
| 10   | 3    |
| 01   | 4    |
| 11   | 5    |
| 000  | 6    |
| 100  | 7    |
```

and so on and so fourth. Currently, the functions i have created to do this work as such

```
from itertools import product


def bit_lookup_num(lookup):
  if lookup == '':
    return -1
    
  bits=[]
  current_len=1
  while lookup not in bits:
    bits.extend(["".join(perm[::-1]) for perm in product(["0","1"],repeat=current_len)])
    current_len+=1
  return bits.index(lookup)

def num_lookup_bit(lookup):
  if lookup == -1:
    return ''
    
  bits=[]
  current_len=1
  while len(bits)-1<lookup:
    bits.extend(["".join(perm[::-1]) for perm in product(["0","1"],repeat=current_len)])
    current_len+=1
  return bits[lookup]
```

Where `num_lookup_bit` functions as my prior example's `functionA`, and `bit_lookup_num` serves as `functionB`. However, my implementation becomes quite slow for large bit sequences, and its due to my use of the `product()` function from itertools. There surely must be a faster way to accomplish this than generating every possibility using `product()` and checking its position in the list, alas i have yet to discover this workaround.

How can i improve upon these functions by avoiding brute-force algorithms?

Comment: when you say "bits" you mean a `str` objct?

Comment: Are you forced to use this particular mapping logic? As in, is the _correct_ mapping the one where you enumerate all the _N_-length products?

Comment: Anyway, if you have enough memory, you can just maintain a giant map that you create up-front. But I feel like there should be an analytic solution as well.

Comment: Ah! This will go in counting order... ok...

Comment: Sorry, you want `01` and `10` as distinct, no? Your table suggests otherwise

Comment: @cadolphs this is *the* order, yes. and juanpa.arrivillaga, it is a str object that contains 0's and 1's. not an actual bytestring.

Comment: Your example sequence doesn't match your code output. 4 => `01`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you and Woodford are correct, that was a mistake on my part. i apologize for any confusion that had caused.

Comment: shouldn't `01` come before `10`? EDIT: oh! didin't notice the `perm[::-1]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no, that was intentional. Its meant to count upwards like binary, so `01` would occur after `10` is overfilled

Comment: how big could `lookup` get?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in my case, as large as 256**3. So for the meantime, your map solution is probably my best bet. But i really feel like there should be some combination of arithmetic functions that could avoid either altogether...

Comment: there almost certainly is, essentially, you can index into a binary bin, then find the number from there and convert the integer to binary, but I don't have the time to think this through at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bit sequences are just, take the binary representation of val+2, chop off the leading `1`, and reverse what's left:

```
def bit_sequence(val):
    # [3:] removes the '0b1'
    return bin(val+2)[3:][::-1]
    # return bin(val+2)[:2:-1] would be a bit faster, but a bit harder to understand

def val_for_bit_sequence(bits):
    binary = '1' + bits[::-1]
    return int(binary, 2) - 2
```

Comment: how did you even figure that out

Comment: Assigning integers to bit sequences usually ends up being some variation of just counting, so I looked for the differences between this pattern and just regular counting in binary and figured out how to compensate for the differences. Adding a `1` digit makes the significant leading zeros no longer leading zeros, and the reversal compensates for the fact that your bit sequences are counting up in little endian instead of big endian.

Answer (score 1):

Incremental approach:

```py
def num_lookup_bit(num):
    x = 2
    bits = ''
    while num >= 0:
        bits += '0' if num%x < x/2 else '1'
        num -= x
        x *= 2
    return bits

def bit_lookup_num(bits):
    x = 2
    num = 0
    for b in bits:
        num += x//2 if b == '0' else x
        x *= 2
    return num-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an inelegant way to do this:

```
import math

def num_lookup_bit(lookup: int) -> str:
    log = int(math.log2(lookup))
    diff = lookup - sum(2**i for i in range(1, log))
    return f"{diff:0{log}b}"

def bit_lookup_num(lookup: str) -> int:
    length = len(lookup)
    return sum(2**i for i in range(1, length)) + int(lookup, 2)
```

They key thing to understand is that you first index into a "bin" which corresponds to the binary digit, then you count from there!

There's probably a super obvious elegant way to do this, but the above seems to work for me.